# Symfony2, Do not use alias in url with KnpPaginatorBundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, knpmenubundle

I'm using KnpPaginatorBundle and I would like to know if it is possible to get an url without alias (**t**.country) like this

```
/travels?sort=country&direction=asc
```

not like this

```
/travels?sort=t.country&direction=asc
```

This the form :

```
<select class="select_styled white_select" id="sort_list" name="option">
            <option value="">-------</option>
    {{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Country A-Z', 't.country', {'sort': 'country', 'direction': 'asc'}) }}
    {{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Country Z-A', 't.country', {'sort': 'country', 'direction': 'desc'}) }}

</select>
```

and this is the Controller :

```
    public function listAction($page, Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');

    $qb = $em->getRepository('ProjectTravelBundle:Travel')->getListTravelsFrontend();

    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $qb,
        $request->query->get('page', $page)/*page number*/,
        10/*limit per page*/
    );

    return $this->render('ProjectFrontendBundle:Frontend:list.html.twig',array(
        'pagination' => $pagination
    ));
}
```

no solution ?

Answer (score 0):

For what I've read right now at [KnpPaginatorBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/templates.md), it seems that you need this code:

```
<select class="select_styled white_select" id="sort_list" name="option">
    <option value="">-------</option>
    {{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Country A-Z', 't.country', {'direction': 'asc'}) }}
    {{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Country Z-A', 't.country', {'direction': 'desc'}) }}

</select>
```

Comment: but this gives me the same result, an url with alias, isn't possible to remove alias from url ?

Comment: @hous This feature has been requested here: https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle/issues/196